# How to find out which 'Apache Configuration File' is currently in use on XAMPP running on Windows10 64-bit operating system?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, httpd.conf, mod-php

I'm using **PHP 7.3.4** on my laptop that runs on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit operating system**.

I've installed the latest version of **XAMPP** installer on my laptop which has installed the **Apache/2.4.39 (Win64)** and **PHP 7.3.4**

For checking which **PHP configuration file** i.e. `php.ini` is in use currently I checked the output of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

I especially checked the below line from the output :

**Loaded Configuration File**   C:\xampp\php\php.ini

Like this I want to find out which **Apache Configuration file** is in use currently. I checked the output of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` but nowhere I found the answer.

I know that `httpd.conf` must be in use but nowhere I found out it mentioned.

Also, on my system I checked the value of **PHPIniDir directive** which specifies the directory that contains the `php.ini` file is present in the file **httpd-xampp.conf** rather than in the file **httpd.conf**.

Why so?

That's why I want to find out the exact **Apache Configuration file** currently being used and its location on my system .

Pleas help me in this regard.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. You cannot get where `httpd.conf` is loaded using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Maybe you can find it in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`. You can call in the `windows prompt`:

`C:\xampp\apache\bin>httpd -V`

But you cannot get the `full path` of `httpd.conf`.

Hope this helps.